# Java regex for substitution - How make it efficient

Tags: java, regex

I've devices a Java regex to perform below substitution

```
Pre-substitution   | Post-substitution
=============================
GOSP_vhqjvfec      | GOSP
INWMDN_10qkva      | INWMDN
OS_INT_ihdqivmf0   | OS_INT
RSO15_1_%I_0gkuns  | RSO15_1
AUDIT124_%I_qkbfn1 | AUDIT124
==============================
```

I've used this regex

```
regular exp  -> (.*?)_%.*|(.*)_.*
substitution -> $1$2
```

I want to know if there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simpler regex:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("_(%\\S*|[^_\\s]+)\\b", "");
```

i.e. match an underscore followed by 2 alternations:

- `%` and 0 or more non-space chars
- 1 or more of non-underscore and non-space chars

This all should be followed by a word boundary.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO6gC2/1)

Comment: Pretty neat approach, nice!

Comment: @anubhava, Thanks for quick reply, I'll test it on Monday

Comment: @anubhava, I'm facing an issue with the above (my bad, I forgot to mention the condition in my question).. If there a value such as OSR_PREP or GOM_GSO_12, it should remain same and there should not be any substitution on it...This is an extension of my question

Comment: @anubhava, for the above condition, if there are only Max. 9 characters & all charaters are in CAPS, there should be no substituion for such values.

Comment: ok you should edit your question and add these examples to make it clear. I will try to modify my regex based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```
_%I.*$|_[^_]+$
```

Comment: Anyway even my one looks easier to read, anubhava's solution runs faster, so it is more efficient (52  steps vs 60 steps on regex101).